# Are cleric domain spells from higher levels added to the previously gained ones or they replace them?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric, character-advancement, domains

When you gain new cleric domain spells at higher levels, do they replace the domain spells you gained at an earlier level? Or do you keep the old spells?

For example, when a cleric is 3rd level, will they have the spells gained at 1st level in addition to the ones gained at 3rd level, or just the domain spells gained at 3rd level?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] or check the [help] to learn more about the site!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Domain spells are always prepared.

The Cleric class description has a small section describing domain spells in general:

> Each domain has a list of spells — its domain spells — that you gain at the cleric levels noted in the domain description. **Once you gain a domain spell, you always have it prepared**, and it doesn’t count against the number of spells you can prepare each day.

So once you reach the level required for new domain spells, *those spells are always prepared*. They do not replace the domain spells of a lower level. They are *always* prepared for the rest of your life. And maybe death if you’re playing that kind of campaign.

Comment: "They are always prepared for the rest of your life." - Unless your domain (or class) somehow changes... Rare though that may be :P

Answer (score 7):

Levels are “gained.”  Someone who levels up to become a 12th-level cleric already “has” 1st level through 11th level, and has every class feature from those levels as well as those from 12th.

This is true of all classes and all class features.  If something were an upgrade or replacement, it would explicitly say that—and off the top of my head, I can’t think of any examples of that (aside from cases where the upgrade or replacement does everything the original does but more/better such as a Paladin's Aura of Protection increasing in diameter at 18th level).

Comment: Honestly, though, this is a totally fair question—I’m not totally sure where it actually *says this*. I’ll dig some more for proper evidence in the morning. If someone wants to beat me to it, I’ll happily upvote.

Comment: Actually i think that a better reading of the rules could have answered my question and i dont know what to do now lol

Comment: Should I delete it?

Comment: @khadzulwarrev do not delete it, it is fine. This site is partially to store knowledge so a future web search for this brings up this question.

Comment: @khadzulwarrev I second TheDragonOfFlame, this is a totally reasonable question. Definitely leave it up.

Comment: I add an example for you of 'getting better' at higher level.

Comment: @khadzulwarrev if we all deleted our questions when they were answered then the next person looking for the answer would have to ask again! :)